# Auto load different pages in php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am using below snippet to load a page content in `#load div`

```
var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
    $('#load').load('load.php?_=' +Math.random()).fadeIn(3000);
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
```

It loads pages after each 10 seconds.

Now come to the point what i want. I have five pages.

I need to set loop that autoload pages in every 2 minutes. And so on and at the end it starts from the beginning.

please help me to make this give me some ideas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `'` instead of `\``

Comment: I'm using (') not (`) Here it is just because of stackoverflow.com restriction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told me the format for your pages so I'm assuming you can use numbers to simply count up.

```
var seed = 0;
var lastPageNumber = 10;
setInterval(function() {

  $('#load').load('load.php?page=' + seed + '_=' + Math.random()).fadeIn(3000);
  if(seed === lastPageNumber) {
    seed = 0;
  }      
  seed++;
}, 120000); // refresh every 120000 milliseconds (120 seconds -> 2 minutes)
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but firebug XHR tools shows that seed++ is not functioning so it always stays load.php?page=0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var i = 0;
var loadPage = setInterval(function() {
    $('#load').load('page'+(i++) + '.php').hide().fadeIn(3000);
}, 2000); //---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----page with number and extension

if(i >= 5){
   clearInterval(loadPage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help but firebug XHR tools shows that it does not stop and 5 and so it did not restart for 0. It just goes on adding.